# Using getch in coding, strange error

Tags: c++

I write this code but vs gives me an error about getch(). What's wrong in my coding????? Before that I used _getch() statement in my codes and have no any problems but know it gives me an error. What's the problem????

error : Error in line 16    error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

```
/***********************************************************\
* This program counts word and characters of a paragraph    *
* Write by : saeid asaadian                                 *
* Create date : 11 - 7 - 2015                               *
* Version : 1.0                                             *
\***********************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int char_counter=0, word_counter=0;
   char ch = 0;
   cout << "Please Type your paragraph (press ENTER for end) : \n";
   cin >> ch;
   while ((ch = _getche()) != '\n') 
   {
      char_counter++;
      if (ch == ' ')
         word_counter++;
   } // end of while loop
   cout << "\nnumber of characters is :" << char_counter << "\nnumber of word is :" << word_counter << endl;
   _getche();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, what's the error?

Comment: I don't see any use of `getch()` in this code.

Comment: the program compiles fine. what error do u see? is that a compiler/linker error or logic error??

Comment: btw, use getchar() which works across various compilers

Comment: this is error : Error in line 16 error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Comment: That's probably not the entire error message. Is the compiler complaining about `"conio.h"`?

Comment: im new in c++ and i recently start learning c++. i don't understand your question but when i press f5 in vs2013 to run this code it says "the project is out of date, whould you to build it ?" i press yes and after that compile runings and give main error "there were build error" and in error window shows "Error line 16 error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated"

Comment: I think you may want to take out the call to cin just prior to your loop.  I think this is eating a character you don't want eaten.

Answer (score 1):

You should change getche() to getchar() because getche is obsolete function.

Anything work fine. ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int char_counter = 0, word_counter = 0;
    char ch = 0;
    cout << "Please Type your paragraph (press ENTER for end) : \n";
    cin >> ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        char_counter++;
        if (ch == ' ')
            word_counter++;
    } // end of while loop
    cout << "\nnumber of characters is :" << char_counter << "\nnumber of word is :" << word_counter << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the header file `#include "conio.h"` to `#include <conio.h>`
Becuase `getch()` functions are defined in this header file.

Comment: Post the error please. Because different compiler use different header files. The problem could be with "conio.h".